# unable to Retrieve Default Windows Administrator Password of EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

When I am trying to retrieve password for one EC2 instance from key pair, I am getting the below error, please help me how to retrieve the password.

```
Password is not available.
This instance was launched from a custom AMI, or the default password has changed. A password cannot be retrieved for this instance. If you have forgotten your password, you can reset it using the Amazon EC2 configuration service.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to change the password so that you can regain access to your Windows instance. This third method is now the recommended method - using AWS Systems Manager. Note: AWS Systems Manager can take a bit of time to understand. Once you do, you will have many new powerful commands.

Run a command to change the Windows password. This [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts) will show you how to use Instance User Data. You will want to run a Windows command `net user Administrator newpassword`. Setup the script and then reboot the instance. The command runs on reboot.

[Resetting the Windows Administrator Password Using EC2Launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Launch.html)

[Reset Passwords and SSH Keys on Amazon EC2 Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-ec2reset.html)